# Where do I configure the pressure sensitivity settings for Sculpt Mode?

Tags: customization, sculpting

I'm currently sculpting hair on my model using my Wacom tablet in Sculpt Mode and I was wondering if there are settings somewhere which I can modify to specify how Blender would react to my pressure input in the context of sculpting.

Comment: you can scale the brush via the [ and ] keys, but I haven't yet found keys to pinch the falloff curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The small buttons next to radius, strength and autosmooth that look like fingers pushing in something will turn that on for you.

[image: Visual Aid]

Comment: Oh, shoooot. It's just right there all along! I feel dumb! Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries, happy sculpting! :D