# Monoprice Pressure Sensitivity not working

Tags: texture-painting, sculpting

I have a monoprice 10x6.25 tablet. Input works just fine, I can move the mouse with the pen, click, right click and drag. However when I attempt to paint or sculpt with the pressure sensitivity button enabled, no pressure is detected.

The driver has a test area that allows me to test sensitivity. I can paint different sized strokes based on pressure in that area without trouble.

The device also appears in the Device Manager as a HID Tablet. I will install Gimp 2.6 for further testing (I am aware of the 2.8 issue) But I'm curious if anyone else with a monoprice tablet had the same issue.

Thanks for your time!

Using Blender 2.78 on Windows 10

**EDIT:**

I downloaded gimp 2.6 for Windows and the pressure sensitivity for the tablet worked right out of the box. Blender is the only program so far that is giving me trouble. See attached image drawn in GIMP:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I retrieved my old Wacom Bamboo Tablet from work (model CTE-450) and plugged it in. Out of the box Blender accepted the pressure sensitivity. I believe this narrows the issue down to specifically *Monoprice* and Blender.

Looks like I'll be carrying my Wacom to and from work for now.

Comment: Have you seen http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62668/where-do-i-configure-the-pressure-sensitivity-settings-for-sculpt-mode ??

Comment: @chicks yes I have, and I've searched multiple other sites. another site suggested the need to restart blender anytime I enable/disable pressure sensitivity. No luck unfortunately!