# My tablet won't work correctly in Blender, I am unsure if it is a problem with Blender or the tablet

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I downloaded blender not too long ago. I have a 8x6" Enthusiast Graphic Tablet by Monoprice. I am unsure if that information matters, but I know some people use a Wacom Tablet in Blender successfully. I don't know if I need to change the settings in Blender or if its just the Tablet. I have looked up tutorials for my problem but so far, nothing has come up. I have already gone to other websites for help but so far, nothing. I was hoping you guys would be able to help me out.

The issue I am having is when I try and use my tablet in Blender, as soon as the pen touches the tablet, the cursor goes to the top left corner and if I click, it closes me out. It will not go anywhere else in Blender no matter where I put the tablet pen, it always goes to that same spot in the corner.

I am unable to Sculpt because of so. I do have a mouse, the mouse works perfectly fine and allows me to work in blender- But I am horrible when it comes to using a mouse since my hands shake. Tablets are easier for me since the pressure sensitivity depends on how hard you press the pen, not by clicking. If that makes sense, haha. 
I am taking classes at school for 3D modeling/ animation that require me to work on them at home, too. My finished products are not coming out as good as i meant to make them and I am afraid I may fail. 
Thank you for reading.

Comment: It might be a problem with drivers of Monospace not working in Blender. Looks like your question isn't the first one about that, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74416/monoprice-pressure-sensitivity-not-working and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50548/graphics-tablet-input-broken-with-blender-2-77-and-2-77a

Answer (score 1):

It has to do the monoprice tablet not being compatible with the windows drivers. You can find the most up to date tablet drivers at [UC-Logic](http://www.uc-logic.com/?lang=en&action=support). Forcing windows to use these drivers kept my monoprice going though windows 8. After updating to Windows 10 it would constantly auto update back to the windows tablet drivers. I I got tired of fighting with it so I retired my monoprice and got a Huoin.